# Polar projection polygon visualization issue

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, visualisation

I am using Natural Earth coastline polygon (NE_10m_land), loaded from a shapefile in QGIS. All displays well (in, e.g., unprojected WGS84, EPSG 4326) - see below:

[image]
But when visualising in a polar projection (here, EPSG:3571, WGS84 in a North Pole LAEA Bering Sea projection), QGIS seems to lose the ability to distinguish between the inside and outside of polygons.

[image]

This does not seem to be a problem with the shapefile ( not well formed polygons) as I can visualize it using ArcGIS just fine.

[image]
So this seems to be  a problem with the rendering engine in QGIS. Any hints?

Edit:
It appears that it is indeed caused by Antarctica. Manual removal of Souther Hemisphere helps.

[image: EPSG:3571 without Southern Hemisphere landmass]

Comment: I think that is Antarctica - try deleting the southern hemisphere

Comment: Thank, will try. Funny it displays correctly in ArcGIS. I lodged a bug issue here too (no action s ofar): https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19191

Comment: It does appear that it is Antarctica - see edit above

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be caused by Antarctica. Hope the edit above helps someone. Yet, not a very nice behaviour from a user perspective, but understandable.